# Rails 4 UJS not firing fail/done/always callbacks

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, jquery-validate

I am using UJS to populate a form within modal, and I am using JQuery Validate to perform validation and submit the form via ajax back to the server.

Everything is working great, the form gets rendered, fields are validated, and the form gets submitted to the server correctly.  The problem is that callbacks hanging off of the `$.rails.handleRemote` function do not fire.

Here is the CoffeeScript that I use for validation and submission (this function is called from with new.js.erb and edit.js.erb:

```
@initializeForm: ->
    $(".note-form").validate ->
        rules: 
            "note[title]" : "required"
    submitHandler: (form) ->
        $.rails.handleRemote($(form))
            .done ->
                alert "You will never see me!"
```

**new.js.erb**

```
$('#modal-window').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'form', :object => @note) %>');

Note.initializeForm();
```

**create.js.erb**

```
var note = new Note();

note.createOrUpdate("note<%= @note.id %>", "<%= @note.title %>", "<%= escape_javascript(render @note) %>");
```

I was able to hack around it by adding this in the application wide script:

```
$(document).on 'ajax:success', '.note-form', ->
    alert "Here I am!"
```

I have validated that I only have one copy of JQuery loaded.

Any ideas would be great!

**Edit**
Here is the compiled JS that is sent to browser:

```
Note.initializeForm = function() {
    return $(".note-form").validate(function() {
        return {
            rules: {
                "note[title]": "required"
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                return $.rails.handleRemote($(form)).always(function() {
                    return alert("You will never see me!");
                });
            }
         };
    });
};
```

Comment: Server-side code is practically useless for troubleshooting client-side (JavaScript) code issues.  Show us the _rendered_ JavaScript and HTML code... in other words, as seen by a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the syntax of the validate call.  I was passing a function instead of an object.

The correct way to call `validate` from CoffeeScript:

```
@initializeForm: ->
    $(".note-form").validate
        rules: 
            "note[title]" : "required"
        submitHandler: (form) ->
            $.rails.handleRemote($(form))
                .done ->
                    alert "You will never see me!"
```